# extract values after first character in data frame column

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

`df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2), V2 = c(10, 20), V3=c("9,1", "13,3,4"))`

```
> df
  V1 V2     V3
1  1 10    9,1
2  2 20 13,3,4
```

Now I want to create a new column 'V4' that takes the value after the first ',' from V3, divides it by the value in V2 and multiplies that by 100

In my example this would be:

(1 divided by 10) * 100 = 10
(3 divided by 20) * 100 = 15

So the output would look like this

```
df_new 

  V1 V2     V3    V4
1  1 10    9,1    10
2  2 20 13,3,4    15
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regex to extract the number after first comma divide it by `V2` and multiply by 100.

```
transform(df, V4 = as.integer(sub("\\d+,(\\d+).*", "\\1", V3))/V2 * 100)
#  V1 V2     V3 V4
#1  1 10    9,1 10
#2  2 20 13,3,4 15
```